Hub Site navigation bar color
I have a Question about the Hub Navigaton Bar, i assigned a Site in SharePoint as a Hub Site, and wanted to use the Navigation bar that is associated with the Hub Function.
The Bar Color is Yellow and it doesn't look nice with the Site Design (the sites have another Color).
is there any Possiblity to change the Yellow Color of the Hubsite Navigation Bar ?
PS: with "Navigation Bar" I mean the Bar that belonges to the Hubsite not the Site Navigation itself.
any Ideas Please ?
Thank you !

This is by design. Child hub sites inherit parent hub look and feel.
Check out this topic: Change color scheme for site belonging to hub in modern SharePoint online

Thank you for the Hint, but I mean only the Navigation Bar Color, that is associated to the Hub as Hub Navigation.
what in the Post that you mentioned in your Comment is about the whole Hub Site theme I beleive, right ?

No, you cannot change the navigation bar color. It's part of the theme.
